# Youtube, loads and plays a list of videos

Tags: android, string, list, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

i'm stuck with implementing following youtube method.

```
public abstract void loadVideos (List<String> videoIds)

Loads and plays a list of videos.
```

basically this is part of my code. 
My ultimate goal is when user click on listitem that video plays or it automatically plays all three videos.
Can someone please help me.

```
 private static final String1[] arry = { 
          new String1("Androidify App", "irH3OSOskcE", false),
          new String1("Chrome Speed Tests", "nCgQDjiotG0", false),
          new String1("Playlist: Google I/O 2012", "PL56D792A831D0C362", true)};




  private static final String KEY_CURRENTLY_SELECTED_ID = "currentlySelectedId";

  private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
  private YouTubePlayer player;
  private ArrayAdapter<String1> videoAdapter1;

  private ListView videoChooser1;
  private StringBuilder logString;
  private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;
  private MyPlaylistEventListener playlistEventListener;

  private int currentlySelectedPosition;
  private String currentlySelectedId;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.player_controls_demo);

    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    videoChooser1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    logString = new StringBuilder();
    videoAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String1>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arry);
    videoChooser1.setAdapter(videoAdapter1);
    videoChooser1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    playlistEventListener = new MyPlaylistEventListener();
    playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();

  }


@Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    this.player = player;
    player.setPlaylistEventListener(playlistEventListener);
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);

    if (!wasRestored) {
      playVideoAtSelection();
    }
    }

  @Override
  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return youTubePlayerView;
  }

  private void playVideoAtSelection() {
    String1 selectedEntry = videoAdapter1.getItem(currentlySelectedPosition);
    if (selectedEntry.id != currentlySelectedId && player != null) {
      currentlySelectedId = selectedEntry.id;
      if (selectedEntry.isPlaylist) {
      player.loadPlaylist(selectedEntry.id);
      } else {
        player.loadVideo(selectedEntry.id);
        player.loadVideos(List<String>,selectedEntry.id);
      }
    }
  }

      @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
      { 
          currentlySelectedPosition = pos;
            playVideoAtSelection(); 
      }




  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putString(KEY_CURRENTLY_SELECTED_ID, currentlySelectedId);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    currentlySelectedId = state.getString(KEY_CURRENTLY_SELECTED_ID);
  }

  private void log(String message) {
        logString.append(message + "\n");
       // eventLog.setText(logString);
      }

 private final class MyPlaylistEventListener implements PlaylistEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onNext() {
      log("NEXT VIDEO");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrevious() {
      log("PREVIOUS VIDEO");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaylistEnded() {
      log("PLAYLIST ENDED");
    }
  }
 private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements PlayerStateChangeListener {
        String playerState = "UNINITIALIZED";

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
          playerState = "LOADING";
          log(playerState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
          playerState = String.format("LOADED %s", videoId);
          log(playerState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
          playerState = "AD_STARTED";
          log(playerState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
          playerState = "VIDEO_STARTED";
          log(playerState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
          playerState = "nCgQDjiotG0";
          log(playerState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
      }
  private static final class String1 {

        public final String title;
        public final String id;
        public final boolean isPlaylist;

        public String1(String title, String videoId, boolean isPlaylist) {
          this.title = title;
          this.id = videoId;
          this.isPlaylist = isPlaylist;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
          return title;
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

After few tries i figured it out, it is partially working in case if anyone else needs it

```
@Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    this.player = player;
    player.setPlaylistEventListener(playlistEventListener);
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);

    if (!wasRestored) {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add((Object)("irH3OSOskcE"));
        arrayList.add((Object)("nCgQDjiotG0"));
        arrayList.add((Object)("irH3OSOskcE"));
        player.loadVideos((List)(arrayList));
      //playVideoAtSelection();
    }
    }
```